# npm ci throws this error when running in Azure Pipeline but not in local PC

Tags: npm, azure-devops

My Azure pipeline keeps failing after this

```yaml
  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: "React: web client - npm ci"
    inputs:
      command: "ci"
      workingDir: "web/client"
```

Output from this task is below:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @progress/kendo-react-animation@7.0.2
npm ERR! Found: react-transition-group@4.4.5
npm ERR! node_modules/react-transition-group
npm ERR!   react-transition-group@"^4.4.5" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-transition-group@"4.4.2" from @progress/kendo-react-animation@7.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@progress/kendo-react-animation
npm ERR!   @progress/kendo-react-animation@"^7.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @progress/kendo-react-animation@"7.0.2" from @progress/kendo-react-data-tools@7.0.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@progress/kendo-react-data-tools
npm ERR!     @progress/kendo-react-data-tools@"^7.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!     5 more (@progress/kendo-react-gantt, ...)
npm ERR!   5 more (@progress/kendo-react-grid, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react-transition-group@4.4.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-transition-group
npm ERR!   peer react-transition-group@"4.4.2" from @progress/kendo-react-animation@7.0.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@progress/kendo-react-animation
npm ERR!     @progress/kendo-react-animation@"^7.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @progress/kendo-react-animation@"7.0.2" from @progress/kendo-react-data-tools@7.0.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/@progress/kendo-react-data-tools
npm ERR!       @progress/kendo-react-data-tools@"^7.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!       5 more (@progress/kendo-react-gantt, ...)
npm ERR!     5 more (@progress/kendo-react-grid, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\npm\cache\_logs\2024-01-10T21_56_36_903Z-eresolve-report.txt
```

when I run `npm ci` on my local PC, everything works fine.

Local PC: node version **18.19.0**

Local PC: npm version **10.2.5**

Azure Pipeline: node version **18.19.0 x64**

Azure Pipeline: npm version **10.2.3**

Comment: 1. You can set up a self-hosted agent on your local machine and run your pipeline use this self-hosted agent. Then check what's the result. 2. According to the error message, you have dependency conflict, please run the same command with `--legacy-peer-deps`. This option tells NPM to ignore peer deps and proceed with the installation anyway.

Comment: How do i setup a self hosted agent?

Comment: Follow [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbrowser#install) to set up a self-hosted agent.